# SQL Server convert varchar string to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi all I have the following stored procedure

```
SELECT DISTINCT QuestionId, AnswerId, COUNT(AnswerId) AS Cntr,
    (SELECT     COUNT(AnswerId) AS ttl
     FROM          QUserAnswers
     WHERE      (QuestionId = QUAM.QuestionId)) AS TtlCnt
FROM         QUserAnswers AS QUAM
WHERE     (QuestionId IN (@QuestionIdIn))
GROUP BY QuestionId, AnswerId
ORDER BY QuestionId
```

which I pass in `@QuestionIdI` in the format '`1,2,3,4,5'` however, its throwing the error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value `'1,2,3,4,5,6'` to data type `int`.

Can anyone give me some pointers to sort it out

Comment: What version of SQL-Server are you using? http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Tim Schelter in the link which he provided :-

First you need to create a function which parses the input

```
 CREATE FUNCTION inputParser (@list nvarchar(MAX))
 RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number int NOT NULL) AS
 BEGIN
 DECLARE @pos        int,
       @nextpos    int,
       @valuelen   int

 SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

 WHILE @nextpos > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
  SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                          THEN @nextpos
                          ELSE len(@list) + 1
                     END - @pos - 1
  INSERT @tbl (number)
     VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
  SELECT @pos = @nextpos
 END
 RETURN
END
```

Then use that function in your SP

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE usp_getQuestion
 @QuestionIdIn varchar(50) 
 AS
 Begin
 Select Distinct QuestionId, AnswerId, COUNT(AnswerId) AS Cntr,
    (SELECT     COUNT(AnswerId) AS ttl
      FROM   QUserAnswers
      WHERE      QuestionId = QUAM.QuestionId) as TtlCnt
 from QUserAnswers AS QUAM
 inner join inputParser (@QuestionIdIn) i ON QuaM.QuestionId = i.number
 GROUP BY QuestionId, AnswerId
 ORDER BY QuestionId
 End

EXEC usp_getQuestion '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
WHERE     (QuestionId IN (@QuestionIdIn))
```

use

```
WHERE charindex(','+cast(@QuestionId as varchar(100))+',',','+@QuestionID+',')>0
```

If you worry about the performace, use split function and join with the main table

Comment: Just to explain why it didn't work: the in operator requires a list of expressions, or a table.  You were passing it a string.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, Ive tried charindex(','+cast(@QuestionId+',',','+@QuestionID+',')>0 and it now says Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'. by the way is SqlServer 2005

Comment: @andrewslaughter Change `cast(@QuestionId+` to `cast(@QuestionId as nvarchar(20))+`

Comment: @andrewslaughter See my edidted reply

Comment: this is my latest incarnation and im sorry to say its still not working, any more clues?                                                            WHERE (QuestionId In(charindex(','+cast(@QuestionId as INT)+',',','+@QuestionID+',')>0))

Comment: You are using it wrong. "QuestionId In" is not needed. See my previous answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply this logic there.

```
Declare @str varchar(100)='''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'''
select @str
DECLARE @s int = 1
select * from emp where CAST(@s as varchar) in ('1','2','3','4','5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change condition:

```
WHERE     (QuestionId IN (@QuestionIdIn))
```

to

```
where (','+@QuestionIdIn+',' like '%,'+convert(varchar(50),QuestionId)+',%')
```

For example for @QuestionIdIn='1,2,3,4,5,6' and QuestionId=3 it means:

```
where (',1,2,3,4,5,6,' like '%,3,%')
```

What's true if 3 is in this list.